# How to run a Prolog program by hand and verify it on a compiler?

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I'm learning logic through Prolog and I was wondering how to manage a Prolog resolution.

Let be the following Prolog program:

```
1. p(a,a,b).
2. p(a,c,c).
3. p(c,c,c).
4. r(X,Y):- p(X,X,Y),write('Test1: ',X,' ',Y),nl,fail.
5. r(X,Y):- p(X,Y,Y),write('Test2: ', X, ' ',Y),nl.
6. go:-r(U,V).
```

> Give the ordering results gave by this code.

7. =6+4:-p(U,U,V), write('Test1: ',U,'',V),nl,fail.

X|U (X had become U) *Do I have to transform all variables?*

Y|V (Y had become V)

8. =7+1:- **write('Test1: ',a,' ',b)**,nl,fail.

U|a (U had become a)

V|b (V had become b)

9. =:-nl,fail.
10. =:-fail.

So I have to reach to the last proposition that weren't wrong, that is to say at 7 and use 3 as far as 2 doens't seems to work there replacing X by a and c.

11. =7+3:-**write ('Test1: ', c,' ',c)**,nl,fail.

U|c

V|c

12. =:-nl,fail.
13. =:-fail.

As far as there is no following proposition that would'nt fail I have to go to **5.**

14. =5+1:-p(U,V,V),write('Test2: ', U,' ',V),nl,fail.

U|a

V|c

15. =14+2:-**write('Test2: ', a,' ',c)**,nl,fail.
16. =:-nl,fail.
17. =:-fail.
18. =14+3:-**write('Test2: ', c,' ',c)**,nl,fail.
19. ... going to an empty clause...

Thus I should have

**Test1: a b**

**Test1: a b**

**Test2: a c**

**Test2: c c**

However, I have an error on SWISH:

```
procedure ` (A:-B)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      swish_trace:swish_call( (go:-r(A,B)))
      '$swish wrapper'((go:-r(A,B)),C)
```

Thus could you help me please understand how to run a Prolog program by hand and verify it on a compiler?
Furthermore do I have to transform all variables when doing X|U (X had become U)?
Last, when is a Prolog considered as ended?

Comment: I don't understand... should be just `?- go.` ?

Comment: @CapelliC Do you mean should it be just `?- go.`? No prolog apply the rules of **resolution** and stops only when it founds an empty clause. Go has to be opposed to the first clause it may be logically conflicting (that's what my teacher told ;) ). In this case the first one is 4 because `r(X,Y)` can be opposed to `r(U,V)`. ;)

Comment: I refer to the error you get from SWISH

Comment: I don't get what you think I should write on the compiler then... Maybe are you saying that it's an odd error message?

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/304899